# Scan all domain workstations for specific registry key/environmental variable

Tags: networking, windows-xp, remote, windows-registry

I'm looking for scripts or software that can scan workstations on a domain for a particular environmental variable (for interest, it was used to store the SOE build version) and generate a report.

Accuracy is key, I don't want any workstations skipped or missed. And considering workstations will need to be powered on for anything to remotely read from the registry (and there's no guarantee they will be), that means something that can sit and run continuously for a while, updating its own records as it goes.

Does anyone know of such a beast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A login or startup script, assigned by GPO, that writes this reg key or variable to a central location (***\\fileserver\share\%COMPUTERNAME%-report.txt***)  would do it. That's how I've done this in the past.

Comment: I'd hoped for something pre-packaged, as I had more variables and reg keys to pull, and needed to compile everything into a non-technical manager readable format by the end of the week.. but my batch-fu isn't as bad as I thought. Between this, psexec for the non domain joined floaters and WoL, I've got a nice little CSV for Excel to turn into shiny pie charts and graphs. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you want something packaged, SCCM is right there for sale. That's a little pricey if your only goal is what you're asking for though. Also, anything that's off-the-shelf is likely going to require more work setting up and deploying than my answer. SCCM can take a dedicated team, if you're big enough.